# How can I shift right after a certain point in the string?

Tags: c

My code provides the following parameters requested by the teacher:

[image]

But the teacher also wants this: "insertChar function should not overwrite any characters. It should insert the new character and offset remaining characters by one index."

how can I set this up? I mean how can I shift a string right from a certain point?

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void insertChar(char string[], char c, int index) {
  int len = 0;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i > index; i--) {
    string[i] = len;
    string[i] = string[i-1];
    string[i-1] = len;
  }

  string[index] = c;
}

int main() {
  char string[100];

  printf("Please input a string \n");
  scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", string);

  printf("Please input the character to be added to string.\n");
  char c;
  scanf ("%c", &c);

  printf("Please input the index which the function will insert the character. \n");
  int index;
  scanf("%d", &index);

  insertChar(string, c, index);
  printf("%s", &string);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: `insertChar(string, 'c', index);` => `insertChar(string, c, index);`

Comment: `char c; scanf ("%s", &c);`. This reads into a 1 character buffer which, at best, can hold *absolutely nothing* but the NUL terminator. Do you mean `"%c"`?

Comment: Why are you re-implementing `strlen`? Or `strcat`? Have you looked at the string functions that C provides by default? I think you need a refresher.

Comment: ohhh tadman, working now i did it wrong because of distraction. must be "%c". thank you too ali

Comment: @tadman not strcat, this is insert character at position 0, which cannot use strcat...

Comment: Is there someone who know how can i do this with strcat?

Comment: There's no need to compute the length.  Walk the string only once, and insert the character when you get to the desired location.  Then either keep walking or use memmove()

Comment: Use `"%99[^\n]%*c"` to avoid UB on long inputs.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `"%99[^\n]%*c"` leads to UB on short inputs like `"\n"`.  `fgets()` is better.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica How can I do, can you explain, please?

Comment: Avoid `scanf()` for user input and read a line with `fgets()` as in `char line[100]; if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) { /* Success, now process line */`, but this is a side issue from the post's goal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `"%99[^\n]%*c"` is well defined on input `"\n"` as long as the value returned by `scanf` is respected and no attempt is made to reference uninitialized data.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I shift right after a certain point in the string?

(OP's `insertChar()` is too broken for repair.)

Watch out for 2 pitfalls: inserting well past the end of the string and exceeding the size of the buffer:

```
#include <string.h>

void insertChar(size_t buffer_size, char string[], char c, size_t index) {
  size_t size_used = strlen(string) + 1;
  if (size_used >= buffer_size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Buffer too small for insertion or existing string.");
  } else if (index >= size_used) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Inserting well past the end of the string.");
  } else {
    // Move the right portion of the string by 1 with memmove
    //      v----------------v Address one past the insertion point
    memmove(&string[index + 1], &string[index], size_used - index);
    //                          ^------------^ Insertion location
    string[index] = c; // Insert
  }
}
```

Usage

```
char string[100];
...
insertChar(sizeof string, string, c, index);
```